# JavaScript TypeError: Cannot read property 'eat' of Undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined, typeerror

I am working on a project that solves the classic "jumbled word" puzzle found in many newspapers. The basic idea of the project is that it accepts a scrambled word (no spaces or special characters), generates every permutation of the word, checks each permutation against a "dictionary" supplied by my professor, then adds each permutation that is actually an English word to an array that is then processed further to come up with the result.

Currently, I'm running into a problem that arises when I attempt to check if a permutation is in the "dictionary". The code below was provided by my professor and creates a "dictionary" from an external text file. According to him, dictionary[w] should return a number paired with the word that represents the word's frequency or "undefined" if the word is not in the dictionary.

```
function readDictionary() {
    /**
     * @type {string[]}
     */
    const lines = fs.readFileSync("count_1w.txt", "utf-8").split("\n");
    var line;
    const dictionary = {};
    for (line of lines) {
        line = line.trim();
        let array = line.split('\t');
        if (array.length > 1) {
            let word = array[0];
            let count = array[1];
            if (lexicon[word]) {
                dictionary[word] = parseFloat(count);
            }
        }
    }  
    return Object.freeze(dictionary); 
}

function getDictionary() {
    if (dictionary === null) {
        dictionary = readDictionary();
    }
    return dictionary;
}

var dictionary = getDictionary();
```

The following code which I have written should return "true" if dictionary[letters] is not undefined...

```
function inDict(letters) {
     if (dictionary[letters] !== undefined){
         return true;
     }
     else{
         return false;
     }
}
```

...however in its current state it throws the TypeError in the title of this post, with 'eat' being the first permutation of the input that is generated. Note that in my actual code readDictionary(), getDictionary(), and var dictionary = getDictionary are all declared above inDict().

If more details are needed please feel free to ask. I've reached the end of my personal knowledge of JavaScript, and multiple Google searches have turned up nothing that has helped in my particular instance. Any suggestions or opinions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: typeof variable != 'undefined'

Comment: or just `return letters in dictionary`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is clear: `dictionary` has the value `undefined`, so why is that?

The problem is that the function **`getDictionary` returns `undefined`**. The condition `dictionary === null` is never `true` because `dictionary` has the initial value `undefined` and `undefined === null` is `false`.

So what you are really doing is

```
var dictionary; // initial value is undefined
dictionary = dictionary;
```

which does nothing.

I don't see why you need `getDictionary` at all. Just initialize `dictionary` directly:

```
var dictionary = readDictionary();
```

Alternatively you could:

Initialize `dictionary` with `null` (but why would you?)

```
var dictionary = null;
dictionary = getDictionary();
```

Compare against `undefined` instead:

```
function getDictionary() {
    if (dictionary === undefined) {
        dictionary = readDictionary();
    }
    return dictionary;
}
```

Overall, `getDictionary` is poorly designed because it has an implicit dependency on `dictionary` but also returns a value.

Comment: That seems to have done it. Seems like my professor provided broken code for this project. I appreciate your help.